# Should I use Angular JS for faceted search?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, faceted-search

I'm planning to build a webpage that compares large amounts of products.
I need faceted search/filters for that, so the visitor can filter the product on price/color etc.

I couldn't find a ready to implement webshop script for that, so I'm planning to build it myself.
I'm a fan of Laravel, but to avoid page refreshes if the user is changing the filters in the side bar, you need a kind of AJAX calls to your Eloquent ORM.

So that's when AngularJS can be handy, but now I'm confused if I do need Laravel for such a stack. Because if you use AngularJS and MongoDB, you don't need Laravel at all.

So I'm not sure what is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I know nothing about Laravel, but a quick google tells me it's a PHP framework for making a restful API.

The 'standard' stack for angular apps at the moment is the "MEAN" stack. That is: MongoDb, Express, Angular, Node. I'm not sure this can be considered a "Best Practice", because it's not necessarily better, but it is definitely the common practice, and as such will be easier to get support and help with.

All that being said, angular really doesn't care about the back-end. It's a front-end framework for making single page web applications. All it really needs is a decent API that you can access by creating a custom service. There is no reason you can't replace node and express with PHP and laravel, and mongo with SQL, you just won't get such a nice acronym!